# PowerPivot Ranking Groups using DAX's Rankx - Ranking Using Sum of a Field

Tags: powerpivot, dax, rank

Am trying to rank groups by summing a field (not a calculated column) for each group so I get a static answer for each row in my table.

For example, I may have a table with state, agent, and sales.  Sales is a field, not a measure.  There can be many agents within a state, so there are many rows for each individual state.  I am trying to rank the states by total sales within each state.

I have tried many things, but the ones that make the most sense to me are:

```
rankx(CALCULATETABLE(Table,allexcept(Table,Table[AGENT]),sum([Sales]),,DESC)
```

and

```
=rankx(SUMMARIZE(State,Table[State],"Sales",sum(Table[Sales])),[Sales])
```

The first one is creating a table where it sums sales without grouping by Agent. and then tries to rank based on that.  I get #ERROR on this one.

The second one creates a table using SUMMARIZE with only sum of Sales grouped by state, then tries to take that table and rank the states based on Sales.  For this one I get a rank of 1 for every row.

I think, but am not sure, that my problem is coming from the sales being a static field and not a calculated measure.  I can't figure out where to go from here.  Any help?

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output that shows what you are trying to do?

Comment: Leonard was kind enough to supply sample input.  Using that, the output would show all North Dakota rows with a 1 because they have the most sales.  Delaware would be 2.  Nebraska would be 3.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data looks something like this...

[image: Table with 3 columns: AGENT, STATE, Sales. There are 6 agents, 3 states and 18 rows (a value for each agent/state combination)]

...have you tried this:

```
Ranking Measure = RANKX(ALL('Table'[STATE]),CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Sales])))
```

The ALL('Table'[STATE]) says to rank all states. The CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Sales])) says to rank by the sum of their sales. The CALCULATE wrapper is important; a plain SUM('Table'[Sales]) will be filtered to the current row context, resulting in every state being ranked #1. (Alternatively, you can spin off SUM('Table'[Sales]) into a separate Sales measure - which I'd recommend.)

Note: the ranks will change based on slicers/filters (e.g. a filter by agent will re-rank the states by that agent). If you're looking for a static rank of states by their total sales (i.e. not affected by filters on agent and always looking at the entire table), then try this:

```
Static Ranking Measure = CALCULATE([Ranking Measure], ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[State]))
```

This takes the same ranking measure, but removes all filters except the state filter (which you need to leave, as that's the column you're ranking by).

Comment: Thank you for your response, Leonard.  That gives me a 1 ranking for everything.  It's the same output as the second option in my original post.  Having a hard time wrapping my mind around why it could be happening.

Comment: It would depend on the data model then. Perhaps your table(s) don't look like the sample table I made up. (And if you do have a problematic data model, it'd be worth finding out what the root problem is: it can make every DAX expression much harder than it needs to be)

Comment: The only two main differences between your data set and mine is that there are a few other fields besides just state and agent.  In my ALLEXCEPT I also specified those fields so it should still theoretically, right?  Or is there a potential problem that can arise there?  The other difference is that in Sales I have a lot of blank entries, but I don't see how that could impact anything.

Comment: Any fields in the ALLEXCEPT will be able to slice/filter/change the rankings. E.g. if you put Age in the ALLEXCEPT, then when you slice on age, the rankings will change. If you leave Age out, then slicing on Age will be ignored. However, the 1 ranking for everything implies a problem with the first Ranking Measure - not the Static Ranking Measure. The formula matches exactly (including the CALCULATE)? You don't have a 2nd table/column for state that you're slicing on? It may be worth trying with sample data in a new model and, if that works, comparing the 2 to see what might be different.

Answer (score 1):

I did figure out a solution that's pretty simple, but it's messier than I'd like.  If it's the only thing that works though, that's okay.

I created a new table with each distinct state along with a sum of sales then just do a basic RANKX on that table.